# Hide last digits of phone number like 99XX XXX XXX PHP or jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this code that outputs the var `$phone`.

```
<span class="row_value phone"><?php echo $this->items->phone; ?></span>
```

Which outputs: 9999 999 999. I want it to output 99XX XXX XXX and display a link below the phone number which say "show phone number" and on click to turn into 9999 999 999.

Comment: did you try anything ? well better keep 99XX XXX XXX as your default value to be viewed and the numbe ryou are fetching keep it hidden

Comment: I tried some code i found here but with no effect, I think the formatting was wrong: <p>My telephone number is <span data-replace="555-41-23">555-XX-XX</span>. If you can not see it, just click it :)</p> ... didnt work

Comment: Try reading the help section on asking questions. If you have tried anything at all, post the code so that people can point you in the right direction. You can't expect people to do the work for you.

Comment: This does absolutely nothing in terms of security. The original numbers are there in the source code, if you want to show the original numbers on click.

Comment: I have tried all of THIS -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334751/jquery-show-and-hide-last-4-numbers-of-a-phone-number With no effect at all

Comment: I want it to hide it from google search, so when peoples search google for the phone number it does not show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this....

**PHP**

```
<?php
    $ph  = $this->items->phone;
    $ph1 = substr($ph,0,2);
    $ph2 = substr($ph,1,strlen($ph));
?>
    <span class="row_value phone"><?php echo $ph1; ?><span id="phone-x" data-data="<?php echo $ph2; ?>"><?php echo preg_replace("/[0-9]/","X",$ph2); ?></span></span>
    <button id="show_ph">show phone number</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#show_ph").click(function() {
    var data = $("#phone-x").html();
    var adata = $("#phone-x").attr("data-data");        
    $("#phone-x").html(adata);
    $("#phone-x").attr("data-data",data);
  })
})
```

[<kbd>**Example**</kbd>](http://jsbin.com/iPaJoFe/1/edit)

Comment: Yes id does, sorry I was doulble loading jquery and causing a conflict. Thx for your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this...
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">


function doChange(){

var pass= '';

var special = "xxxxxx";


    s = document.randform.name.value;
    var string_length = s.length-2;
    pass +=s.substring(0,2);
    for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
        var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * special.length);
        pass += special.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
    }

    document.getElementById('dyn').innerHTML = pass;
    document.getElementById('dyn').style.color = 'red';
}
function doChange2(){

    document.getElementById('dyn').innerHTML = s;
    document.getElementById('dyn').style.color = 'blue';
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="randform">
<input type='text' name='name' value='' /> <i id='dyn' onClick="doChange2();">Hello</i>
<input type="button" value="Create number" onClick="doChange();">&nbsp;

</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your post, I have tried it, ran it, but I already have the phone numbers stored in a variable called "phone". I want it to be outputed masked and have a <a href="#">Show phone number</a> wich changes the masked phone variable from 99 xxxx to original state.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution to your problem. This works for me, you can use substr_replace().

Syntax:

```
substr_replace(string,replacement,start,length)
```

For example:

```
echo substr_replace($mobile_number, 'XXXXXXXX', '1', '8');
```

Here, 1 is the starting length and 8 is the length to which 'x' to be shown.