# Hidding part of email and contact number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been following these examples on [jQuery - Show and hide last 4 numbers of a phone number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334751/jquery-show-and-hide-last-4-numbers-of-a-phone-number)  as I'm trying to add a small javascript on a wordpress website but I can't get it working I'm very new to javascript and am learning as I go along, so please be patient.

I loaded the javascript in the footer before and after jquery but cant get it to work. I basically need to hide part of the number so I can track the clicks for the number via tag manager.

The test page i've created is http://gautengelectricfencing.co.za/test/

I will appreciate if someone can assist

Thank you

Comment: FYI: Java Has nothing to do with JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just use a simple one like this, use a simple click handler:

```js
$(function () {
  $("[data-tel]").click(function () {
    if (confirm("Are you sure?"))
      $(this).text($(this).data("tel"));
  });
});
```

```css
[data-tel] {cursor: pointer; border-bottom: 1px dotted #999;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Phone: <span data-tel="+449876543210">+4498765XXXXX</span></p>
```